# Where can I change the Gradle version in an android project?

Tags: gradle

Each time when I try to open an android project downloaded from Google Android samples, Android Studio would try to download different version of Gradle automatically. This is really frustrating and troublesome to me since the downloading is very slow in China.

I would like to stop the automatic download and appoint the latest version to replace the one in a sample project. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In AS, open the settings dialog ("File" -> "Settings") and select "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Gradle". In this dialog you can select "Use local gradle distribution" to use whatever Gradle version you have locally installed on your machine.

This may however break some projects since some plugins require a certain gradle version. The default setup (using the gradle wrapper) takes care of this.

Alternatively, you can also change the gradle version used by the wrapper by modifying it in file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. The same warning about incompatible versions applies.